# Power Automate - compose in apply to each

Tags: power-automate

Can someone explain how come using `compose` action in `Apply to each` create an array of all objects and not overwrite the `compose` action everytime?

I've seen it in numerous blog posts as a time saver instead of using `append to variable`, but never understood it why `compose` behave like this.

**Example:**

Input: `[1,2,3]` Output: `[1,2,3]`

[image: Flow structure of apply to each usage]

Comment: Ideally, you should not be able to access the output of Compose 2 outside the apply to each action, like given here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFuLF.png. I am guessing you have added the expression in Compose 3 manually and not from "dynamic content" section.

Comment: thats correct, it has been added manualy.

Comment: ok, current loop value of Compose 2 cannot be accessed outside the apply to each action. Maybe some bug (or weird feature) from Microsoft end it shows the complete array as output.